# Web Services - How to get failed backup jobs from NetBackup

Tags: backup, symantec

I work with SharePoint. I was given a project where I need to call NetBackup web services and download all the failed Backup jobs. Backup Status = failed or something like it.

All I know they (backup team) gave me a url http://netbk004/Operation/opscenter.home.landing.action? I have worked with asmx before but I have no clue how to consume exceptions from NetBackup. Is there an API that comes with NetBackup that I can use to populate a SharePoint list? Or web services, it doesn't matter as long as I can download the exceptions to a SharePoint List.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about through the webservice, but I know you can access the state of backup jobs by running the bpdbjobs command and parsing through the output.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Netbackup activity monitor. Then filter the "Status" column with ">1".

This will give you all tha failed jobs